# Popup remains at top of page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Web surfing I found a hotspot/popup that I incorporated into my page, but lost the link to the site where I found it.  Now, I changed something and the popup displays at the top of the image.  The left and right seem to work fine, but the popups do not align with the top of the pins on the image. [image] looking at the image, the popup should be displayed near the red pin for Wk6.  I am not sure what I changed that now makes it display improperly.  The website is https://2af.team/afa/booth.php

Any help would be appreciated.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Second Air Force</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>">
  </head>
  <body>
    <?PHP include "disclaimer.php";?>
    <header class="imgbox">
      <img src="./images/2AF_banner-min.png" alt="Second Air Force" class="banner-center-fit">
    </header>
    <section>
      <div class="container">
        <img class="img-center" src="./images/boothall-min.png" alt="Booth Poster">
        <div class="all-tooltip">
          <div class="tooltip tooltip-1">
            <div class="pin">
              <ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
            </div>
            <div class="tooltip-content">
              <div class="arrow"></div>
                <div class="content">
                  <h1>It's Time: Second Air Force invests in the next generation</h1>
                  <p>KEESLER AIR FORCE BASE, MIssissippi<br>
                  <a style="color: blue" href="https://www.2af.aetc.af.mil/News/Article-Display/Article/3288234/its-time-second-air-force-invests-in-the-next-generation/" target="_blank">https://www.2af.aetc.af.mil/News/Article-Display/Article/3288234/its-time-second-air-force-invests-in-the-next-generation/</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="tooltip tooltip-2">
            <div class="pin">
              <ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
            </div>
            <div class="tooltip-content">
              <div class="arrow"></div>
                <div class="content">
                  <h1>CSAF 23 Message to Airmen: Follow Through</h1>
                  <p>OFFICE OF THE CHEIF OF STAFF, Washington DC<br>
                  <a style="color: blue" href="https://www.af.mil/Portals/1/documents/2023SAF/CSAF_23_Message_to_Airmen_Follow_Through.pdf" target="_blank">https://www.af.mil/Portals/1/documents/2023SAF/CSAF-23-Message-to-Airmen-Follow-Through.pdf</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="tooltip tooltip-3">
            <div class="pin">
              <ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
            </div>
            <div class="tooltip-content">
              <div class="arrow"></div>
                <div class="content">
                  <h1>Air Force Revamps 'Zero Week' at BMT to Better Prepare Recruits for Stress</h1>
                  <p>JOINT BASE SAN ANTONIO-LACKLAND, Texas<br>
                  <a style="color: blue" href="https://www.airandspaceforces.com/air-force-zero-week-bmt/" target="_blank">https://www.airandspaceforces.com/air-force-zero-week-bmt/</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="tooltip tooltip-4">
            <div class="pin">
              <ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
            </div>
            <div class="tooltip-content">
              <div class="arrow"></div>
                <div class="content">
                  <h1>Where Trainees Transform into the World's Greatest Airmen</h1>
                  <p>JOINT BASE SAN ANTONIO-LACKLAND, Texas<br>
                  <a style="color: blue" href="https://www.airforce.com/training/military-training/bmt/overview/" target="_blank">https://www.airforce.com/training/military-training/bmt/overview/</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="tooltip tooltip-5">
            <div class="pin">
              <ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
            </div>
            <div class="tooltip-content">
              <div class="arrow"></div>
                <div class="content">
                  <h1>DoD Fire Academy: Fired up for training</h1>
                  <p>GOODFELLOW AIR FORCE BASE, Texas<br>
                  <a style="color: blue" href="https://www.aetc.af.mil/News/Article-Display/Article/2970829/dod-fire-academy-fired-up-for-training/" target="_blank">https://www.aetc.af.mil/News/Article-Display/Article/2970829/dod-fire-academy-fired-up-for-training/</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="tooltip tooltip-6">
            <div class="pin">
              <ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
            </div>
            <div class="tooltip-content">
              <div class="arrow"></div>
                <div class="content">
                  <h1>Keesler AFB unveils innovative classroom environment for ‘Mach 21 Airmen’</h1>
                  <p>KEESLER AIR FORCE BASE, Mississippi<br>
                  <a style="color: blue" href="https://www.af.mil/News/Article-Display/Article/1732995/keesler-afb-unveils-innovative-classroom-environment-for-mach-21-airmen/" target="_blank">https://www.af.mil/News/Article-Display/Article/1732995/keesler-afb-unveils-innovative-classroom-environment-for-mach-21-airmen/</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="tooltip tooltip-7">
            <div class="pin">
              <ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
            </div>
            <div class="tooltip-content">
              <div class="arrow"></div>
                <div class="content">
                  <h1>US Air Force Leadership Insights Maj. Gen. Michele C. Edmondson, Commander, Second Air Force on Technical Training Transformation</h1>
                  <p>KEESLER AIR FORCE BASE, Mississippi<br>
                  <a style="color: blue" href="https://www.halldale.com/articles/21667-mst-us-air-force-leadership-insights-maj-gen-michele-c-edmondson-commander-second-air-force-on-technical-training-transformation-and-more" target="_blank">https://www.halldale.com/articles/21667-mst-us-air-force-leadership-insights-maj-gen-michele-c-edmondson-commander-second-air-force-on-technical-training-transformation-and-more</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  <footer class="foot">
    <?PHP include "navbar.php";?>
  </footer>
  <script>
    const tooltips = document.querySelectorAll(".all-tooltip .tooltip");
    const fullDiv = document.querySelector("section");
    const container = document.querySelector(".container");
    let timeoutId;
    window.addEventListener("resize", contentPosition);
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", contentPosition);

    function contentPosition() {
    tooltips.forEach((tooltip) => {
        const pin = tooltip.querySelector(".pin");
        const content = tooltip.querySelector(".tooltip-content");
        const arrow = tooltip.querySelector(".arrow");
        const pinLeft = pin.offsetLeft;
        if (pinLeft + content.offsetWidth / 2 > fullDiv.offsetWidth) {
          const extraLeft = fullDiv.offsetWidth - (pinLeft + content.offsetWidth / 2);
          // console.log('right-conflict', tooltip)
          content.style.left = pinLeft - content.offsetWidth / 2 + extraLeft - 30 + "px";
          content.style.top = pin.offsetTop + 30 + "px";
        } else if (
          pin.offsetLeft + container.offsetLeft < content.offsetWidth / 2
        ) 
        
        {
          // console.log('left conflict', pin.offsetLeft)
          content.style.left = pinLeft - container.offsetLeft + "px";
          content.style.top = pin.offsetTop + 30 + "px";
        } else {
          content.style.left = pinLeft - content.offsetWidth / 2 + "px";
          content.style.top = pin.offsetTop + 30 + "px";
        }
          arrow.style.left =
          pinLeft - content.offsetLeft + pin.offsetWidth / 2 + "px";
      });
    }
    tooltips.forEach((tooltip) => {
    const pin = tooltip.querySelector(".pin");
    const content = tooltip.querySelector(".tooltip-content");
    pin.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
        tooltip.classList.add("active");
    });
    pin.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
        timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        if (!tooltip.classList.contains("content-hover")) {
            tooltip.classList.remove("active");
        }
        }, 2000);
    });
    content.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        tooltip.classList.add("active");
        tooltip.classList.add("content-hover");
    });
    content.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
        timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        tooltip.classList.remove("active");
        tooltip.classList.remove("content-hover");
        }, 2000);
    });
    });
    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
body {
background-color: #112349;
}

h1{
  font-size: 6rem;
}

h2{
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: rgb(44, 44, 135);
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  font-weight: 800;
}

ul{
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

ul li{
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

hr{
  opacity: 50%;
}
  
li{
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-x: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 10 5 10 5;
  text-align: left;
}

.li1size{
  width: 20%;
}

.li2size{
  width: 40%;
}

.li3size{
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
}

.li4size{
  text-align: center;
  width: 15%;
}

video{
  max-width: 1400px;
}

#drag_drop{
  background-color : #f9f9f9;
  border : #ccc 4px dashed;
  line-height : 250px;
  padding : 12px;
  font-size : 24px;
  text-align : center;
}

a{
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.banner{
max-width: 100%;
margin: auto;
}

.disclaimer{
  position: sticky;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  left:0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #eeecec;
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.disclaimer p{
  font-size: .75rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.imgbox{
display: grid;
height: 100%;
}

.banner-center-fit{
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100hv;
margin: auto;
display: inline-block;
}

.center-fit{
max-width: 33%;
max-height: 100hv;
margin: auto;
display: inline-block;
}

.fblogo {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 30%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-size: 3vw;
}

#images{
  text-align: center;
}

.img{
  width: 50%;
}

nav{
  display: flex;
  font-size: 2rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgb(73, 73, 73);
}

.links{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.links a{
  color: black;
}

.links a svg{
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
}

.links img{
  height: 3rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.center{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}

.div-center{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.div-size{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section{
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.div-size-2{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.img-center{
  width: 100%;
}

footer{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4rem;
}

table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

th{
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

td{
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: whitesmoke;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 33%;
}








@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  
  h1{
      font-size: 3rem;
  }
  
  h2{
      font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
  
  h3{
      font-size: 2rem;
  }
  
  p{
      font-size: 1.6rem;
  }

video{
  max-width: 650px;
}

  table{
      width: 100%;
      border-collapse: separate; 
      border-spacing: 1em;
      border: 0;
  }

  th{
      font-size: 2rem;
      padding-top: .8rem;
      padding-bottom: .8rem;
      padding-left: .8rem;
      padding-right: .8rem;
  }

  td{
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      padding-top: .8rem;
      padding-bottom: .8rem;
      padding-left: .8rem;
      padding-right: .8rem;
  }

  .disclaimer p{
      font-size: 1rem;
  }
}

  
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

  h1{
      font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
  
  h2{
      font-size: 2rem;
  }
  
  h3{
      font-size: 1.8rem;
  }
  
  p{
      font-size: 1.4rem;
  }

  video{
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  
  table{
      width: 100%;
      border-collapse: separate; 
      border-spacing: 1em;
      border: 0;
  }

  th{
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      padding-top: .5rem;
      padding-bottom: .5rem;
      padding-left: .5rem;
      padding-right: .5rem;
  }

  td{
      font-size: 1rem;
      padding-top: .5rem;
      padding-bottom: .5rem;
      padding-left: .5rem;
      padding-right: .5rem;
  }

  li{
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .li1size{
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .li2size{
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .li3size{
      text-align: left;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .li4size{
      text-align: left;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
  .disclaimer p{
      font-size: .5rem;
  }

  .vertical{
      display:flex;
    }

}


/* Hotspot styling below */
*  
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.container img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.all-tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.tooltip-content {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #00000020;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 90vw;
  max-width: max-content;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  /* left: -50%; */
  z-index: 2;
}

.tooltip-content .arrow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  top: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%) rotate(0deg);
}

.popup {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:20000;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: none;
  background-color:#dd8;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.pin {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 50%;
  left: 80%;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pin:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: puls-effect 1s ease infinite;
}

.tooltip.active .tooltip-content {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
  display: block;
}

/* Custom Style for tooltip-1 */

.tooltip-1 .pin {
  top: 7.5%;
  left: 28%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(250, 0, 0);
}

.tooltip-1 .tooltip-content {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.tooltip-1.active .tooltip-content {
  display: flex;
}

.tooltip-1 .tooltip-content .img {
  width: 25%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.tooltip-1 .tooltip-content .content {
  width: 75%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.tooltip-1 .tooltip-content .content h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.tooltip-1 .tooltip-content .content p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.tooltip-1 .tooltip-content .content button {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #00000020;
}

/* Custom Style for tooltip-2 */

.tooltip-2 .pin {
  top: 9.9%;
  left: 75.35%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.tooltip-2 .tooltip-content {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.tooltip-2.active .tooltip-content {
  display: flex;
}

.tooltip-2 .tooltip-content .img {
  width: 25%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.tooltip-2 .tooltip-content .content {
  width: 75%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.tooltip-2 .tooltip-content .content h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.tooltip-2 .tooltip-content .content p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.tooltip-2 .tooltip-content .content button {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #00000020;
}

/* Custom Style for tooltip-3 */

.tooltip-3 .pin {
  top: 31.03%;
  left: 45.4%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.tooltip-3 .tooltip-content {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.tooltip-3.active .tooltip-content {
  display: flex;
}

.tooltip-3 .tooltip-content .img {
  width: 25%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.tooltip-3 .tooltip-content .content {
  width: 75%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.tooltip-3 .tooltip-content .content h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.tooltip-3 .tooltip-content .content p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.tooltip-3 .tooltip-content .content button {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #00000020;
}

/* Custom Style for tooltip-4 */

.tooltip-4 .pin {
  top: 59.9%;
  left: 24.6%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.tooltip-4 .tooltip-content {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.tooltip-4.active .tooltip-content {
  display: flex;
}

.tooltip-4 .tooltip-content .img {
  width: 25%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.tooltip-4 .tooltip-content .content {
  width: 75%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.tooltip-4 .tooltip-content .content h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.tooltip-4 .tooltip-content .content p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.tooltip-4 .tooltip-content .content button {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #00000020;
}

/* Custom Style for tooltip-5 */

.tooltip-5 .pin {
  top: 59.6%;
  left: 67.5%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.tooltip-5 .tooltip-content {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.tooltip-5.active .tooltip-content {
  display: flex;
}

.tooltip-5 .tooltip-content .img {
  width: 25%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.tooltip-5 .tooltip-content .content {
  width: 75%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.tooltip-5 .tooltip-content .content h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.tooltip-5 .tooltip-content .content p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.tooltip-5 .tooltip-content .content button {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #00000020;
}

/* Custom Style for tooltip-6 */

.tooltip-6 .pin {
  top: 58.4%;
  left: 86.5%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.tooltip-6 .tooltip-content {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.tooltip-6.active .tooltip-content {
  display: flex;
}

.tooltip-6 .tooltip-content .img {
  width: 25%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.tooltip-6 .tooltip-content .content {
  width: 75%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.tooltip-6 .tooltip-content .content h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.tooltip-6 .tooltip-content .content p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.tooltip-6 .tooltip-content .content button {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #00000020;
}

/* Custom Style for tooltip-7 */

.tooltip-7 .pin {
  top: 74.96%;
  left: 37.9%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.tooltip-7 .tooltip-content {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.tooltip-7.active .tooltip-content {
  display: flex;
}

.tooltip-7 .tooltip-content .img {
  width: 25%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.tooltip-7 .tooltip-content .content {
  width: 75%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.tooltip-7 .tooltip-content .content h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.tooltip-7 .tooltip-content .content p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.tooltip-7 .tooltip-content .content button {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #00000020;
}


/* tooltips for wing page */

/* Custom Style for tooltip-w1 */

.tooltip-w1 .pin {
  top: 49.8%;
  left: 19.6%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(250, 0, 0);
}

.tooltip-w1 .tooltip-content {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.tooltip-w1.active .tooltip-content {
  display: flex;
}

.tooltip-w1 .tooltip-content .img {
  width: 25%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.tooltip-w1 .tooltip-content .content {
  width: 75%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.tooltip-w1 .tooltip-content .content h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.tooltip-w1 .tooltip-content .content p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.tooltip-w1 .tooltip-content .content button {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #00000020;
}

/* Custom Style for tooltip-w2 */

.tooltip-w2 .pin {
  top: 24.5%;
  left: 27.5%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.tooltip-w2 .tooltip-content {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.tooltip-w2.active .tooltip-content {
  display: flex;
}

.tooltip-w2 .tooltip-content .img {
  width: 25%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.tooltip-w2 .tooltip-content .content {
  width: 75%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.tooltip-w2 .tooltip-content .content h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.tooltip-w2 .tooltip-content .content p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.tooltip-w2 .tooltip-content .content button {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #00000020;
}

/* Custom Style for tooltip-w3 */

.tooltip-w3 .pin {
  top: 7%;
  left: 58%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.tooltip-w3 .tooltip-content {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.tooltip-w3.active .tooltip-content {
  display: flex;
}

.tooltip-w3 .tooltip-content .img {
  width: 25%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.tooltip-w3 .tooltip-content .content {
  width: 75%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.tooltip-w3 .tooltip-content .content h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.tooltip-w3 .tooltip-content .content p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.tooltip-w3 .tooltip-content .content button {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #00000020;
}

/* Custom Style for tooltip-w4 */

.tooltip-w4 .pin {
  top: 24.5%;
  left: 87%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.tooltip-w4 .tooltip-content {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.tooltip-w4.active .tooltip-content {
  display: flex;
}

.tooltip-w4 .tooltip-content .img {
  width: 25%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.tooltip-w4 .tooltip-content .content {
  width: 75%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.tooltip-w4 .tooltip-content .content h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.tooltip-w4 .tooltip-content .content p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.tooltip-w4 .tooltip-content .content button {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #00000020;
}

/* Custom Style for tooltip-w5 */

.tooltip-w5 .pin {
  top: 49.9%;
  left: 96.1%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.tooltip-w5 .tooltip-content {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.tooltip-w5.active .tooltip-content {
  display: flex;
}

.tooltip-w5 .tooltip-content .img {
  width: 25%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.tooltip-w5 .tooltip-content .content {
  width: 75%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.tooltip-w5 .tooltip-content .content h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.tooltip-w5 .tooltip-content .content p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.tooltip-w5 .tooltip-content .content button {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #00000020;
}



/* Puls Effect For Pins */

@keyframes puls-effect {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(3);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"` is not completely doing its job. We are talking missing the boat by, like, 50ms or thereabouts. So, the top few pins might be caught in their correct position, but the lower pins are still at the top of the page.

**Explanation:**

Using DevTools, **on the Sources tab**, open Booth.php and click on the number 232 in the left margin. Doing so will put a breakpoint on that line, and when you refresh via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>F5</kbd> (leaving DevTools open!), you will see the pins all aligned at the top of the page at the moment when javascript is grabbing all their top positions... so the popups will pop up at the top of the page.

However, if you put the breakpoint on line 237 instead, let the script halt at that point, remove the breakpoint (by clicking on it again) and  press the <kbd>|></kbd> (play) button at the top of the right-side panel, you will see all the pins in their correct positions on the page - and the javascript forEach loop will cache their correct positions for later display.

**SOLUTION:**

Wrap your call to function `contentPosition()` in a setTimeout, or create a new function that does that. For example, this would work:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", waitThenDo);

function waitThenDo(){
   setTimeout( () => {
      contentPosition();
   }, 500);
}
```

The above waits 1/2 second (500ms) before running the contentPosition() function. You might have to play with that number a bit, but you may be able to bring it below 100ms - not that anyone would ever notice a delay even if it was 2000 ms...

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response and explination as to why.  This resolved the problem.  Thank you again.